# How does one bias plotted data, to line up multiple series of data without modifying the input data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to change a data series from a formula like `=SHEET!$L$500:$L$750` to `=(SHEET!$L$500:$L$750)+120` and Excel is refusing to allow this.

How can I achieve this offset (or bias) of 120 degrees to this data series, and consequently subtract 120 degrees to another set on the same plot - without modifying the input data or adding extra columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series formulas don't allow calculations. If you don't want to use a helper column in the worksheet, you can set up a named formula with the Name Manager in the Formulas ribbon.

Create a new name, for example "ModifiedSeries" and use the formula you had above. In my screenshot, I used

```
=(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$10)+3
```

Then add a series (or edit the existing one), and instead of the range in the Series values, enter the name you just created. Note that it must be preceded by the sheet name, otherwise Excel will not allow it. To quickly write the sheet name, type a = sign, then click any cell in the sheet and use the backspace key to remove the cell reference, then type the name you used or pick it with F3.

[image]

In my screenshot, I added a new series with the named formula in addition to the existing series, so you can see the difference.

[image]

Instead of hard-coding the value to add to the original series data, you can make it more dynamic by pointing to a cell. In this animated screenshot, the name has the formula

```
=(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$10)+Sheet1!$B$13
```

[image]